# How to remove item in array every X times until array length equals 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Given an array with five values:

```
let names = ["Bob", "Brian", "Jen", "Sarah", "Joe"]
let number = 3
```

I would like to go through the array and remove the third value (using the number variable, in this example it would be `Jen`, and then continue to count up so that the next item to be removed would be `Bob`. Bob is removed since it is the third value AFTER `Jen`, with the loop starting back at the beginning after it exceeds the length of the array. I want to continue looping through in this manner until there is only item left in the array.

To put it more visually the results would look like this for each iteration:

- Bob
- Brian
- ~~Jen~~
- Sarah
- Joe

---

- ~~Bob~~
- Brian
- ~~Jen~~
- Sarah
- Joe

---

- ~~Bob~~
- Brian
- ~~Jen~~
- Sarah
- ~~Joe~~

---

- ~~Bob~~
- ~~Brian~~
- ~~Jen~~
- **Sarah**
- ~~Joe~~

Comment: Addition and modulus are your friends.

Comment: I would suggest trying to break down the problem into parts. A hint: you can use the modulus operator (`%`) to get the index after the end of the array...

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on how you get to Joe from Bob (4 steps) and to Brian from Joe (2 steps). What is your rule here?

Comment: @ggorlen: Since Jen is no longer in the array Bob to goes from Bob -> Brian -> Sarah -> Joe. Then since Joe is no longer in the array, from Joe to Brian: Joe -> Brian -> Sarah -> Brian. Note that the index overflows the boundary and starts from the beginning again.

Comment: I think I got it--thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem). I validated this using an input test case from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) and it passes, but I'd be curious to see how it fares on additional input since it seems suspiciously less verbose than all code examples on RC.

```js
let names = ["Bob", "Brian", "Jen", "Sarah", "Joe"];
let number = 3;

for (let n = (number % names.length) - 1; names.length > 1;) {
    names.splice(n, 1);
    n = (n + number - 1) % names.length;
}

console.log(names);
```

Here's a snippet of running the RC test:

```js
// https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Josephus_problem
// n=41 k=3
// killed: 2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 0 4 9 13 18 22 27 31 36 40 6 12 19 25 33 39 7 16 28 37 10 24 1 21 3 34 15
// survived: 30

const killed = "2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 0 4 9 13 18 22 27 31 36 40 6 12 19 25 33 39 7 16 28 37 10 24 1 21 3 34 15".split(" ");
const survived = "30";

let k = 3;
const prisoners = [];
const killSequence = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 41;) { prisoners.push(""+i++); }

for (let n = (k % prisoners.length) - 1; prisoners.length > 1;) {
  killSequence.push(prisoners[n]);
  prisoners.splice(n, 1);
  n = (n + k - 1) % prisoners.length;
}

if (JSON.stringify(killSequence) === JSON.stringify(killed) && survived === prisoners[0]) {
  console.log(`Test passed. Survivor is ${prisoners[0]}.`);
}
else {
  console.log("Test failed");
}
```

Comment: Log `i`, `names[i]` and `names.length` right before the `splice` and you'll see that the index will be out of bounds at a certain point.

Comment: Interestingly, that doesn't appear to affect the result. `--len` gives an incorrect answer. What do you propose?

Comment: This abuses splice not throwing an error when trying to access an index out of bounds. For example, it will still give the proper answer when the count number is bigger than the array length

Comment: I see that and you're correct to point it out. There must be some error that would fail on another input, but I'm not seeing an obvious solution right now. I'll look into it. Either way, there is an arithmetical solution to this which is probably the way to go if this is a coding challenge.

Comment: `i = (number % names.length) - 1` so that numbers >= names.length work

Comment: @ggorlen I would be interested in an arithmetic solution if you find a general one. Mathworld has a non-obvious (to me) solution but only when number == 2: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JosephusProblem.html

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer because it seems to return the result that is expected but I see what @Asthmatic means about the splice abuse

Comment: @Kupe that was for an old version of the code, so that comment is outdated.

Comment: @Kupe he fixed that, the only thing now is this answer doesn't return the right result when your count is bigger than the number of people in the array

Comment: @Asthmatic do you have some test cases for this?

Comment: Set numbers to 8, expected is Bob but it gives Jen

Comment: @Asthmatic excellent, thanks, I'll look into it further and figure something out. If OP just needs the perfect answer in the interim, might as well grab some code from the Rosetta link and call it a day though.

Comment: the fix is `let n = (number % names.length) - 1`

Comment: @Asthmatic Ah, sure. I'll plug that in. Even so, I'm not 100% my solution passes all edge cases but I'll keep looking at it. Let me know if anything else comes up and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**: Flavius Josephus was a roman historian of Jewish origin. During the Jewish-Roman wars of the first century AD, he was in a cave with fellow soldiers, 41 men in all, surrounded by enemy Roman troops. They decided to commit suicide by standing in a ring and counting off each third man. Each man so designated was to commit suicide. (When the count came back around the ring, soldiers who had already committed suicide were skipped in the counting.) Josephus, not wanting to die, placed himself in position #31, which was the last position to be chosen. In the general version of the problem, there are n soldiers numbered from 1 to n and each k-th soldier will be eliminated. The count starts from the first soldier.

Result contains array in which elements will be eliminated. Your answer will be the last element.

```js
function josephus(array, count) {
    // Return store
    const store = [];

    // Counter for each time the element should be spliced
    let counter = 0;

    // Array index position
    let index = 0;
    while (array.length > 0) {
        // This is because 'array' is treated like a circular array
        index = index % array.length;
        if (++counter === count) {
            // Remove the element from the array and push onto the store.
            // The first element is used, hence [0]
            store.push(array.splice(index, 1)[0]);

            // Reset the counter
            counter = 0;

            // Move back one index value
            index--;
        }
        index++;
    }

    return store;
}

// Example

console.log(josephus(["Bob", "Brian", "Jen", "Sarah", "Joe"], 3));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. You could take the last index of your `store` array and return that to get the final result he wants, but you still didn't calculate the result using the algorithm he asked for

Comment: Actually it does the same he asks and I could have returned the last element even, OP can do it himself, the extra bit is for the community who wants to see how it is done.

Comment: This answer does a great job of explaining the background of the problem and showing how you go to the answer. I think changing your function to `return store[store.length - 1];` would be more clear for anyone coming across this.